# Generate one Stream from multiple Suppliers

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use Java 8 Lambda/Stream API for modeling a simple producer/consumer system, just like:

```
    Stream<Sample> samplesFlow = Stream.generate(new SampleSupplier());
    samplesFlow.forEach(new SampleConsumer());
```

I realized that "scale" to several consumers was pretty simple:

```
    samplesFlow
        .peek(new SampleConsumer1())
        .peek(new SampleConsumer2())
        .forEach(new SampleConsumer3());
```

But what about adding new producers to the system? Is there some idiomatic or "elegant" way to **generate a Stream from several infinite Suppliers??** Like:

```
Stream.generate(new SampleSupplier1(),new SampleSupplier2());  // made it up
```

Each supplier simulate a network listener getting data from a remote source.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want the resulting stream to look like? Do you want each `Supplier` to be called repeatedly, or just once, or a certain number of times, or what? Perhaps you could clarify by providing an example.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand correctly: you want to generate a stream from whichever Supplier has an item available? The order is more or less defines by which supplier already has a new item available?

Comment: Well in my case which I would think is pretty typical I have two methods I'm calking, one that gets one string and a second that gets a different string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn’t specify how you want to combine the supplied values.

If you want to have the values alternating, a solution would be:

```
Stream.generate(supplier1).flatMap(x->Stream.of(x, supplier2.get()))
```

---

If you want to have some kind of pair, you can use

```
Stream.generate(()->new Pair<>(supplier1.get(), supplier2.get()))
```

though it is up to you to write the `Pair` class as the jdk does not offer such a class. (You could abuse `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` but that’s rather nasty).

---

If you have a finite `Stream` you can use [`Stream.concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) to create a stream which will process all items of the first stream before the items of the second, however, streams created using a `Supplier` are infinite by default so you have to use [`limit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) on the first stream before you can concat it to another stream, so it’s not a general solution.

---

If you want to query each `Supplier` exactly once, you can use

```
Stream.of(supplier1, supplier2).map(Supplier::get)
```

though, of course, if you don’t need lazy evaluation of the `Supplier`s, a

```
Stream.of(supplier1.get(), supplier2.get())
```

would do as well.

Comment: I thought perhaps mananoreboton wanted to stream multiple Streams or Suppliers sequentially.  That can be accomplished with [Stream.concat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-).

Comment: @VGR: that doesn’t work as streams generated from a `Supplier` are *infinite* so you can’t process one stream after the other. I’ll extend my answer as this seems to pop up over and over.

Comment: Very good point.  I don't know why that wasn't immediately obvious to me…

Comment: A `Supplier` provides a single value each time you call it. It's `generate` that makes it infinite, by calling the `Supplier` repeatedly. The OP might want to use **n** `Supplier` instances to produce a finite stream of **n** values. I'll ask.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: you’re right, the question is a bit underspecified. However, to me a `Supplier` is an infinite source conceptually as it doesn’t mandate how often `get` will be called and there is no such thing like a `hasNext` method (unlike `Iterator`). But I added the once-per-`Supplier` alternatives.

Comment: Because "statistical rigor" I think samples should alternate.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, another option, which hides the complexity of the implementation, is to use

```
StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator<T> spliterator, boolean parallel)
```

to generate the stream and delegate a [Spliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) to traversing elements of different sources.

There are certain considerations to keep in mind for implementing `forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action)`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
public static Supplier<String> getString(Supplier<String> one, Supplier<String> two){
   return ()-> one.get() + two.get();
}
```

Comment: With this we would be losing lazyness. In case that doesn't matter I think it would work with varargs:

`public static Supplier<String> getString(Supplier<String> suppliers){
   //iterate suppliers
}`