# Is it possible to combine the result of method calls from List <Supplier <String>> writtenLines into a new Supplier using the Stream API?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

Is it possible to combine the result of method calls from `List<Supplier> writtenLines` into a new `Supplier` using the Stream API, without using multi-line lambda blocks, so that the solution could work for a list of any length?

```java
public class Experiment { public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Supplier<String>> writtenLines = List.of(Experiment::write,Experiment::write, Experiment::write);

    Supplier<String> combined = () -> new StringJoiner(", ")
            .add(writtenLines.get(0).get())
            .add(writtenLines.get(1).get())
            .add(writtenLines.get(2).get())
            .toString();

    System.out.println(combined.get());
    //output: "String, String, String"
}

public static String write() {return "String";}

}
```

Comment: `Supplier<String> ac = () -> writtenLines.stream().map(Supplier::get).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` ?

Comment: do take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311535/generate-one-stream-from-multiple-suppliers